# Socket Connection with Authentication

Tags: dart

We are connecting using TCP with authentication in java and the connection is getting established successfully.

We found ServerSocket and Socket class in dart in io package. However not sure how to connect a server with authentication parameters or credentials in DART. With host address and port is working fine for anonymous users. But not sure how to pass the credentials or which methods accepts with credentials.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you'd have to use an encrypted TLS socket through [SecureServerSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/SecureServerSocket-class.html). Here's a [good article](http://jamesslocum.com/post/70003236123) demonstrating how it's used.